# how to change ionic project name

Tags: ionic-framework

Please am trying to change my ionic project name, for example, change from 'oldApp' to newApp but when I rename the project folder and build the app I still have the old name I used when starting the app. Please how do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First think you change name from config.xml if yes then remove platform and then add again and your name is change.